# Terminology: FNP, with P replaced by NP?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes

Consider these two classes of search problems:

1. Search problems with poly-sized solutions s.t. verifying solutions is in **P**.
2. Search problems with poly-sized solutions s.t. verifying solutions is in **NP**.

Class 1 is **FNP**. Is there any commonly used name for class 2?

---

Examples of problems in these classes:

1. Given a graph with *n* nodes, find a proper 3-coloring.
2. Given a graph with *n* nodes, find a partial 3-coloring such that the first *n*/2 are colored and the partial coloring can be extended to a proper 3-coloring.

Note that these two problems are, in essence, equivalent, but the key point is that a solution to problem 2 requires a proof, while a solution to problem 1 is already a proof.

Comment: It should be in '$F\Sigma_2^P$' however is there a hierarchy?

Comment: In other words, these are just FNP problems composed with a projection. I don’t think there is an established name (even though the concept is quite natural and comes up now and then). It makes no sense to call it $F\Sigma^P_2$, as the latter would denote $\Sigma^P_2$ search problems, that is, with a coNP verifier.